# Makefile: echo not properly printing

Tags: linux, makefile, echo

I have below command

```
$ echo \\newcommand{\\coverheight}{11.0in} > tmp
$ cat tmp
echo \\newcommand{\\coverheight}{11.0in} > tmp
```

But when I'm using same `echo` command in make file, it's not properly writing to file.

```
# Makefile
all:
       printf '\\newcommand{\\coverheight}{11.0in}' > tmp
```

After running `make', the output is:

```
$ cat tmp 

ewcommand{
```

How to write to a file properly using `Makefile` using `echo`?

Answer (score 3):

`make` just sends a recipe (except for splitting long lines) to your shell and do not interpret it. So it is your shell that interprets it.

So your shell run this `echo` and `printf` commands. And shells like bash or zsh use builtin commands for echo and printf (if you don't say to use the `/bin/echo` command explicitly).

And there is a difference between behaviour of builtin commands between shells. What is more is that you can use one shell for running interactive commands and `make` use different shell (by default /bin/sh) for handling recipies.

Here is an example of difference between shells. When I run in `echo \\newcommand` in `bash` I get:

```
$ echo \\newcommand
\newcommand
```

And when I run `echo \\newcommand` in `zsh` I get:

```
$ echo \\newcommand

ewcommand
```

I suspect that you get different result because of it. And actually `printf '\\newcommand{\\coverheight}{11.0in}'` must be more correct because it uses strong quoting.

Anyway one way to print in makefile seems to be using external command /bin/echo:

```
all:
       command echo '\\newcommand{\\coverheight}{11.0in}' > tmp
```

Or use strong quote as you already have done:

```
all:
       printf '\\newcommand{\\coverheight}{11.0in}' > tmp
```